# Mockito: Mock object based on another

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a mocked object, say `Car porsche`. It has 4 wheels, 1 windscreen,1 engine and name *Porsche*. This is done via `when()` and `thenReturn()`.

I want to create another mocked Car instance, say *trabant*, that will behave (again `when()` and `thenReturn()`) exactly as the *porsche* instance, only will return a different name.

Is it possible to create the 2nd mock based on the 1st one without repeating all the `when()` and `thenReturn()` steps?

Comment: How about creating a sub class of cars? E.g. ConventionalCar extends Car. Then overriding the parent Car methods with these specific characteristics. (I sounded like I knew what I was talking about there)

Comment: Alternatively try `enum`s to give each car a type and store this information in that `enum` state.

Comment: Hm, I don't want to change the domain model because of some technical testing requirements.

Comment: The short answer is no.  Mockito does not have the feature you describe.  It might be worth putting in a feature request though; you can't be the first person who has wanted this, and you won't be the last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about creating a private method in your test that sets the common expectations on a given mock object?

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is what I have. I am just curious whether Mockito has some support to clone mocked behavior.