# Mockito let mock inherit stubs from already existing mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have two mocked objects from the same class only difference between the two  objects is a different state. Before I can test the state difference I need to stub some methods, this means I have to do it for both objects which doesn't seem efficient to me.

I have following setup for a unit test on java:

```
@Mock
private CuratorFramework zkClient;
@Mock
private CuratorFramework zkClientNotStarted;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() {

    when(zkClient.getState()).thenReturn(CuratorFrameworkState.STARTED);
    when(zkClient.checkExists()).thenReturn(existsBuilder);
    when(zkClient.exampleMethod()).thenReturn(exampleObject);
    ...

    when(zkClientNotStarted.getState()).thenReturn(CuratorFrameworkState.LATENT);
    when(zkClientNotStarted.checkExists()).thenReturn(existsBuilder);
    when(zkClientNotStarted.exampleMethod()).thenReturn(exampleObject);
    ...
}
```

Which rubs me the wrong way because there is a lot of repeated code and couldn't find anything that resemble something like this:

```
@Mock
private CuratorFramework zkClient;
@Mock
private CuratorFramework zkClientNotStarted;    
@Mock
private CuratorFramework zkClientBase;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() {

    when(zkClientBase.checkExists()).thenReturn(existsBuilder);
    when(zkClientBase.checkExists()).thenReturn(existsBuilder);
    when(zkClientBase.exampleMethod()).thenReturn(exampleObject);
    ...

    zkClient.inheritStubs(zkClientBase)
    when(zkClient.getState()).thenReturn(CuratorFrameworkState.STARTED);

    zkClientNotStarted.inheritStubs(zkClientBase);
    when(zkClientNotStarted.getState()).thenReturn(CuratorFrameworkState.LATENT);

}
```

Is there a way to clone/copy a mock to a new mock which inherits the initialized stubs? Or is this wrong use case for the Mockito framework?

Only similar question I found is this one: [Mockito: Mock object based on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046661/mockito-mock-object-based-on-another)
And that one is asked more than 5 years ago. I hope something has changed during that time.

Comment: Why don't you just refactor the repeated code into its own method, and call it twice?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem that's how I have it now but still it would be nice to have such a method in the framework.

Comment: You can make feature requests to the Mockito team at https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues.  I'm not sure how quickly you'll get a response, as I'm not sure how busy they are.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will make a feature request for this

Comment: why not reusing the mock itself instead of creating separate ones?

Comment: I like to make happy and sad path variables of my class to improve readability of a test. For example I know that variable zkClientNotStarted is a instance of my class that has a state "not started" and I can use it appropriately for that instead of using a generic variable and making my stubs in the test method itself, which in my opinion clutters the test method and decreases readability.